# How to get some value from Reducer Ngrx

Tags: redux, ngrx

I have the following reducer

```
import { EntityState, createEntityAdapter } from '@ngrx/entity';
import { createFeatureSelector } from '@ngrx/store';

export const pageAdapter = createEntityAdapter<Page>({
  //selectId: (collection: Collection) => collection.id,
});

export interface State extends EntityState<Page> {
}

const defaultPage = {
    ids: ['kHnryus'],
    entities: {
        'kHnryus': {
        id: '83nryus',
        title: 'How to create a blog with Angular4 Ngrx',
        description: 'How to create a blog with Angular4 Ngrx',
    }
  },
  success_create: false
}

export const initialState: State = pageAdapter.getInitialState();

// Reducer
export function pageReducer(
    state: State = initialState,
    action: actions.PageActions) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case actions.ADD_ALL: {
            return pageAdapter.addAll(action.pages, state);
          };
        case actions.SUCCESS: {
            return {success_create: true}
        };
        default:
            return state;
        }

}

// Create the default selectors
export const getPageState = createFeatureSelector<State>('page');

export const {
    selectIds,
    selectEntities,
    selectAll,
    selectTotal,
  } = pageAdapter.getSelectors(getPageState);
```

I want to get the boolean variable `success_create`  of the state in my component.

Basically , I want that if there is `SUCCESS`, I should be able to get a `success_create` true in the component class. I have no idea as to how to do this and even if it's possible.

If it is, please how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure to remove `defaultPage` constant as you are not maintaining it within your reducers and you are already using [@ngrx/entity](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/docs/entity) for that. The `success_create` should be defined as follow:

```
export interface State extends EntityState<Page> {
  success_create: boolean;
}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<Item> = createEntityAdapter<Page>({
  selectId: (page: Page) => page.id,
  sortComparer: false
});

export const initialState: State = adapter.getInitialState({
  success_create: false,
});
```

Then, after your *default selectors* add a third one that uses `getPageState` selector and gets one step deeper into your state:

```
export const getSuccessCreate = createSelector(
  getPageState, 
  (state: State) => state.success_create
);
```

Then make your component/service listening to it directly like:

```
this.created$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromPages.getSuccessCreate));
```

*note: the pipe is optional here and if used then `select` should be imported from `@ngrx/store` as it is done [in the official ngrx demo app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/example-app/app/books/containers/collection-page.ts). pipe allow you to work with lettable rxjs operators. you can read more about it [here](https://blog.hackages.io/rxjs-5-5-piping-all-the-things-9d469d1b3f44).*

Comment: Thanks but I get the following error ```error TS2552: Cannot find name 'select'. Did you mean 'onselect'?
 error TS2322: Type 'EntityState<Page> & { success_create: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'State'.
  Types of property 'success_create' are incompatible.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false'.```

Comment: I initialize my state this way ```export const initialState: State =  pageAdapter.getInitialState();``` How do I add ``success_create`` to the state?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I hope it answers those questions now.

Comment: Thanks!. Works great!

Comment: I need some help here: I get this weird error ```ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at eval (entity.es5.js:48)``` using this switch statement ```switch (action.type) { case actions.ADD_ALL: return adapter.addAll(action.pages, state); case actions.SUCCESS: { return {success_create: true} }; default: return state; }``` However if I use the switch statement without ```case actions.SUCCESS: { return {success_create: true} };``` everything works fine

Comment: yes that is also wrong as it is overriding all the state and returns only success_create. it should be `case actions.SUCCESS: { return {...state, success_create: true} };` instead.

Comment: Thank you man! I don't know how  I can pay back for your help. Is there any social medial I can follow u on? Thanks so much.

Comment: you are welcome man. there is nothing to pay. we've been all there and we got help at some point. I'm glad I could help back. thanks. I'm not really active in SM but if u use twitter then you'll find me under username @salem_85